# How to read and print Ansible set_fact array in unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I created a String array using set_fact which contains path to different files as below.

```
   - name: set_fact
     set_fact
       fpath: []
     set_fact:
       fpath: "{{ fpath + [ BASEPATH ~ '/' ~ item|basename ] }}"
     loop: "{{ Source_Files.split(',') }}"
     vars:
      fpath: []

   - name: Printing fpath
     debug:
       var: fpath
```

I pass the variable fpath to a shell script as below:

```
   - shell: "~/backup.sh '{{ fpath }}' > ~/backup.log"
```

Below is my backup.sh

```
echo "Prameter 1:"$1 > ~/param.out

IFS=
FPATH=`python <<< "print ' '.join($FPATH)"`
echo "${FPATH[@]}"
for a in "$FPATH"; do
  echo "Printing Array: $a"
  echo $a >> ~/stuffarray.txt
done
```

Prameter 1 print all the three files in the below format

Output:

```
Prameter 1:[u/tmp/scripts/file1.src, u/var/logs/wow.txt, u/tmp.hello.exe]
```

However the conversion of $1 which is a python string array to a Unix shell script array is not happening and it does not print any value for Unix shell script array. This is more of a passing python style string array and reading it in the shell script by looking through the values.

I'm on the latest version of ansible and python.

Can you please suggest how can I pass the  the python string array from ansible to a shell script variable so I could loop through it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable *fpath* is cleared on each iteration of the loop

```
   - name: set_fact
     set_fact:
       fpath: "{{ fpath }} + [ '{{ BASEPATH }}/{{ item | basename }}' ]"
     with_items:
       - "{{ Source_Files.split(',') }}"
     vars:
       fpath: []
```

Correct

```
   - name: set_fact
     set_fact:
       fpath: "{{ fpath|default([]) + [ BASEPATH ~ '/' ~ item|basename ] }}"
     loop: "{{ Source_Files.split(',') }}"
```

, or if *fpath* might have been used before

```
   - set_fact:
       fpath: []
   - set_fact:
       fpath: "{{ fpath + [ BASEPATH ~ '/' ~ item|basename ] }}"
     loop: "{{ Source_Files.split(',') }}"
```

(not tested)

Comment: I removed vars: entry and tried your suggestion but now I get fpath is undefined error. Can you suggest how do I declare this under the same task?

Comment: If I remove the debug the error goes away but sadly the output remains same. Note: echo "Parameters:" $@ prints all the files in shell script but the appending 'u' and $1 showing only the first file name remains

Comment: Edit the question and post `msg: "{{ Source_Files }}"`

Comment: Edited the question to better represent the issue.